# my tomcat uses wrong JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm new to Tomcat. their is something wrong about Tomcat 7 on my ubuntu 10.10.

when I start Tomcat like this

```
llchli@llchli-virtual-machine:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin$ ./catalina.sh  run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_45
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

although cannot start Tomcat this way, it echos `Using JRE_Home  /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_45`, which is the correct `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` on my computer.

but when I start Tomcat with `sudo` like this

```
llchli@llchli-virtual-machine:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin$ sudo ./catalina.sh  start
[sudo] password for llchli: 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

it echos `Using JRE_HOME:        /usr`,which is not the correct `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` on my computer. But it start Tomcat correctly.

my `/etc/environment` is

```
llchli@llchli-virtual-machine:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin$ sudo cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_45/bin"
LANGUAGE="en"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_45"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib"
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47"
```

I'm a bit puzzled about this.And when I use `daemon.sh` like this, it generate errors.

```
llchli@llchli-virtual-machine:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin$ sudo ./daemon.sh run
Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr
Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr
Cannot locate JVM library file
Service exit with a return value of 1
```

It echos `cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr`. I'm so confused.

Any helps and advise will appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use `service tomcat7 start`? Have you installed the `tomact7` package? Or have you installed it manually?

Comment: @ortang   I download '.tar.gz' file and unzip it on '/usr/local/'

Comment: Ok, so you installed it manually, i suggest you to use the package system. Only install software manually if you **really** have to. That will keep your system clean, plus it is very unlikely that you will ever update the installation you installed (eg. security fixes). If you use the package, everything will work out of the box.

Comment: just a tip for debugging that issue: edit the script and add `set +x`, use `env` to show the current environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like "sudo" is not passing your JAVA_HOME and JAVA_PATH through to the child process.

When you run a command using "sudo" the environment variables are set according to what the sudoers file says.  My reading of the "sudoers" manual entry is that the default is to NOT pass variables through.  But according to the "sudo" manual entry, there is a command syntax variation that allows you to pass environment variables using "VAR=value" ...

I suggest that you read the manual entries for "sudo" and "sudoers" carefully, and then read your system's "/etc/sudoers" file to understand how it is behaving.

---

Having said that, launching services from the command line using "sudo" is not a good idea, especially if you are talking about "production" services.  And you are generally better off using the service wrappers provided by your distro's packaging, rather than a non-packaged install from the "upstream" project.

Comment: The "/etc/environment" has already set the System-wide environment variables. so "sudo" wont use environment variables in "/etc/environment" files?

Comment: Lich - you need to read the manual pages.  They will tell you what "sudo" will be doing.  To answer your question, it depends if that file is being read / sourced by either shell initialization or the tomcat scripts themselves.  Certainly, that file is not read (directly) by either sh / bash or sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Sudo resets the environment variables. When you run sudo, JRE_HOME is reset to its default (probably null) and Tomcat will assume its own default (/usr). **You can run sudo with the -E switch to preserve the environment.**

Are you sure, you must run the script as root? I have no idea how to set up Tomcat, but it is usually a good practice to run servers as a dedicated user instead of as root.

Answer (score 0):

As i already state in a comment, i strongly suggest you to use the package system to install software, it it's available in the repository. (plus there are ppa's for nearly everything). That way you will keep your system tidy and you won't have worry about things not working (usually).

My suggestion is to remove your current manual install and install the `tomcat7` package.

```
apt-get install tomcat7
```

For further configuration, use the file `/etc/default/tomcat7`. To start/stop/restart use the command `service tomcat7 {start|stop|restart}`.

Using the package tomcat7 the tomcat instance will run as it's own user, and **not** as root, and that's good, since a service **should not** run as a user with full privileges.

I am aware that i am actually not answering your question with the environment variables. But using the suggested way, you will not face that problem to begin with.

Comment: I'll try it. But the issue dose confuse me. So I want to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

it is all said, it means adding to /etc/sudoers a line with:

Defaults    env_keep += "JAVA_HOME JRE_HOME"